# if user start typing in textbox value change to input else if user didn't type any thing value change to an specific string in C#

Tags: c#, search, textbox, user-input

I have a listview and created a textbox to search itmes in that list!
everything is ok about searching!
but problem is I want my search box to be like this:
at first Searchbox.Text="Search ..." and if user started typing in that searchbox change to that keyword! else(if) searchbox got empty Searchbox.Text change to "Search ..." again!
maybe it's a little complicated! but i tried 1-2 hours on it! and couldn't make it!
I have used Timers,checkboxchange event,booleans,...! but couldn't make it! :(
Please Help!
*my Searchbox name here is textbox1.
Some Codes I tested:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = textBox1.Text;

        /*
        if (!keywordentered_bool)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
         */

        if (str != "")
        {


           //Doing Search operations!
                search_bool = true;
            }
            else
            {//Doing Search operations!

                search_bool = true;

              //  keywordentered_checkbox.Checked = true;

                Searchtextbox_Timer.Interval = 100;
                Searchtextbox_Timer.Enabled = true;
                Searchtextbox_Timer.Tick += Searchtextbox_Timer_Tick; 
                //textBox2.Visible = false;

            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (search_bool)
            {
                listView1.Items.Clear();
                label1.Visible = false;
                listView1.Items.AddRange(Originalplaylist_list.ToArray());
                if (!search_bool)
                {
                    listView1.Items[MusicLogindex_list[MusicLogindex_list.Count - 1]].ForeColor = Color.Cyan;
                }
                else if (search_bool)
                {//Doing Search operations

            search_bool = false;

            Searchtextbox_Timer.Interval = 100;
            Searchtextbox_Timer.Enabled = true;
            Searchtextbox_Timer.Tick += Searchtextbox_Timer_Tick; 
            //textBox2.Visible = true;
           // keywordentered_checkbox.Checked = false;

        }
    }
void Searchtextbox_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!search_bool)
        {
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Location = textBox1.Location;
            //textBox1.Text = "Search ...";
            //textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Gray;

            //textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
        }
        else 
        {
            textBox2.Visible = false;
         //   textBox1.Text = "";
         //   textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;

         // textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
        }
        Searchtextbox_Timer.Enabled = false;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: Winforms or Asp.net webforms?

Comment: refer this link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/589115/TextBox-with-Placeholder

Comment: @FrebinFrancis i think the link you refered is what I'm looking for but unfortunately demo download link does not work! :/

Comment: @ACE you try with the source code link?

Comment: I downloaded it but didn't test it yet because it's just a class!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71365/discussion-between-ace-and-frebin-francis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just psuedocode but the concept is there and you need to implement the text change event for searching , you can do additional changes in event handler.

```
Textbox myTxtbx = new Textbox();
myTxtbx.Text = "Enter text here...";

myTxtbx.OnFocus += OnFocus.EventHandle(RemoveText);
myTxtbx.LoseFocus += LoseFocus.EventHandle(AddText);

public RemoveText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myTxtbx.Text = "";
}

public AddText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(string.IsNullorEmpty(myTxtbx.Text))
        myTxtbx.Text = "Enter text here...";
}
```

This is an example shows for a dynamic textbox control, you can add these events to your control and use the same code for make it work.

Or you can use this plugin

[Visual Studio gallery plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1e5295a5-d7bd-4789-bced-361c608a3a7e)

Another plugin you can use for this purpose

[Textbox with placeholder](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/589115/TextBox-with-Placeholder)

Hope this helps.

Comment: at first thanks for your help!
then I give it a try but I think it wouldn't the thing i want!

Comment: what is your actual need. you just want to show a placeholder like thing isn't it?

Comment: it's a little bad i don't know what placeholder is exactly!
but when i saw the picture in that link I think that's what I want!

Comment: @ACE i updated my answer with a plugin link you can just install that file and you will get an additional textbox control on your toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Frebin Francis my problem solved!
I downloaded the source code from this link [TextBox With Placeholder](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/589115/TextBox-with-Placeholder)
and added it to my project! then add it to my form and yeah! :)